# Allow moderators to rollback locked posts (more easily)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities, rollbacks, locked

Locked posts really are *locked* to most users. To moderators, however, locked posts are substantially less locked. Moderators can edit them, post comments to them, delete comments from them, and even if need be *unlock* them.

There is a curious gap in moderator powers, however. Moderators cannot rollback a locked post. A not uncommon use of locking (at least on Mathematics, where I <s>rule</s> reside) is when a user is continually defacing their question (because they'd really rather delete it, but cannot due to answers) and you just want to hit pause on that situation.

I have just recently experienced a case where a user re-defaced their question within 20 seconds of my having rolled it back. When faced with a user who is this determined to deface their posts, a much easier workflow would be to first lock the post and *then* put it into a previous good state. I should now note that there *are* ways of doing this.

1. As moderators can edit locked posts, just go to the source of the previous good revision, copy it, and make a good new revision.
2. Moderators can edit revisions, and simply "editing" and saving an old revision will effectively roll it back. (This I have only recently become aware of.)

But if a moderator attempts to simply rollback a locked post in the usual manner, they are met with a popup declaring

[image: You can not rollback a locked post.]

This makes no sense to me: I'm a moderator gosh darn it!

Since there are methods for moderators to *effectively* rollback locked posts, wouldn't it be easier to just allow us that small additional privilege to *actually* rollback locked posts?

Comment: Just FYI, this is probably going to be a "I'm a bored developer in this code anyway so what the hell" sort of request, since - as you note - there are multiple ways of accomplishing this already, and it's not commonly needed.

Comment: Why are users who deface their questions not suspended?

Comment: @Ramhound For a first infraction on a single post a suspension is probably ramping things up too far too fast. Contacting the user and explaining the SE principles and norms is, IMHO, a better first step, but this in itself doesn't prevent further defacements. (Of course if this is part of a larger pattern of defacements, then stronger action may be necessary.)